# Use 'change' on listener on input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to do simple data injection inside a simple Input redux form Field.
Let me explain :

I have one big form, and when the user is writing inside "LastName" Input, I just want to inject the value to the second Field as "LastNameFather".

Pretty simple imo,

I made a formvalueSelector, and get the first Input value.

```
const selecor = formValueSelector('MyForm')

const mapStateToProps = (state,props) => {

    const name = selector(state,"nameOne")

    return {
     name : name
    }}
```

And I was using componentWillReceiveProps to handle the writing and use props change to inject my value.

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (props) => {
     props.name != null ? props.change("name2",props.name) : null 
}
```

Now, when I write inside my first Field, there's infinite rerender. As you can see, I have to test props.name != null before change my second Field.

anyway, what I missed ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you bound dispatch to `props.change`?

Comment: Yep, I can see my action is dispatched correctly. 
I don't know what wrong.

Comment: I will not go your way @GreGGus, I prefer to do `onBlur` listener on `Field` of `lastname` and there I will go for the `() => props.change(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. GreGGus, according to the React Js official documentation "Note that React may call this method (componentWillReceiveProps) even if the props have not changed, so make sure to compare the current and next values if you only want to handle changes. This may occur when the parent component causes your component to re-render."
You may try that.